# NavigationManager from within a eventcallback trigger will result to a crash in .net 8 blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, .net-8.0

Im upgrading my .net 6 to .net 8 as result some of the functions are not working property.
In this case navigationManager doesnt work properly if it is within a eventHandler.

Lets say that i have have an object that has a Property
public event EventHandler OnKicked;

and then in Home.Razor  i have it like this in my OnParameterSet Method

```
obj.OnKicked+= (x, y) =>
   {
       navigationManager.NavigateTo("/youarekicked");
   };
```

This worked fine in .net 6 but now in .net 8 I get this error

Error: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.NavigateToCore(String uri, NavigationOptions options)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.NavigateToCore(String uri, Boolean forceLoad)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.NavigateTo(String uri, Boolean forceLoad, Boolean replace)
at SpyGame.Components.Account.IdentityRedirectManager.RedirectTo(String uri) in

What is changed? and why am i getting this with the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

> What is changed?

Nothing in this area that I know of.

> and why am I getting this with the upgrade?

Don't know.  But I'm guessing your doing something wrong in "upgrading my .net 6 to .net 8 "  What Render mode are you using and where have you set interactivity?  Is the notification object a service?

Here's a very simple demo page to show it working.  I'm running this in Net8.0 Blazor ServerInteractive/Global interactivity.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.DoChange">Change</button>

@code {
    private PageState _pageState = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //_pageState.OnChanged += this.OnChange;
        _pageState.OnChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
        };
    }

    private Task DoChange()
    {
        _pageState.NotifyChange(this);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnChange(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }

    public class PageState
    {
        public event EventHandler? OnChanged;

        public void NotifyChange(object? sender)
            => this.OnChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```